# Как сделать, чтобы рейтинг зависел от количества слушателей?

Tags: php

Есть рейтинг радио-шоу. Можно голосовать За и Против, но это как бы не интересно, было бы здорово если бы рейтинг радио-шоу зависел от количества слушателей которые слушали данное радио шоу.

Я не могу сообразить как это реализовать? Как считать рейтинг и как учитывать слушателей среднее значение или как?

Может есть идеи какие-нибудь?

Comment: ЭМ????
Ну просто используй число уникальных радиослушателей. Ты ведь способен отследить количество выходных потоков в данный миг. Чем тебя не устраивает?

Comment: думал над этим! по большей части проблема, как прибавлять рейтинг т.е. как учитывать если каждый раз прибавлять рейтинг хреново. Есть мысль записывать данные сколько слушателей слушало на той недели и если на следующей недели привышает то рейтинг увеличивается. Это только один вариант =)

Comment: это скорее вопрос из области маркетинга и статистики, чем программирования. можно например так - берем статистику за много выпусков, считаем среднее и среднее отклонение, отбрасываем результаты превышающие среднее отклонение, считаем ариф среднее. для сравнения с другими передачами, делаем с ними то-же самое, сортируем по получившемуся количеству слушателей, приделываем какую-нибудь шкалу - смотрим рейтинг. Хотя по мне - рейтинг по кол-ву не показатель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Брать информацию сколько человек прослушал за сеанс / сутки. Считать общий среднее прослушивание не совсем корректно.

Возьмем к примеру, человек может увеличить рейтинг на 1. Т.к. сутки вряд ли кто-то будет сидеть, то систему популярности можно сделать по параболе, т.е.:

**Рейтинг = Корень( Часов просидел / 24 )**

т.е. имеем:

```
0 = 0
30 минут = 0.144
1 час = 0.2
2 часа = 0.28
4 часа = 0.4
12 часов = 0.7
24 часа = 1
```

И дальше по пользователям суммировать эти рейтинги. Каждый день можно делать новый рейтинг, но при этом показывать вчерашний рейтинг.

Естественно можно добавить коэффициент к рейтингу.

Comment: самое интересное решение - спасибо! наградил бы да вот только нечем =(

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).